# Can this be solved algebraically? $2^x (6 - x) = 8x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working on this problem for a few days, but I haven't been able to find $x$ algebraically. (Maybe I'm missing something obvious?)

$2^x (6 - x) = 8x$

Using a MATLAB program, I found the solutions $ x = 2, 3, 4 $.

[I tried using Wolfram|Alpha,](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex+%2a+%286+-+x%29+%3D+8x) but since it didn't provide steps, I assume it solved the equation numerically too. Which is not very elegant.

Follow up: I guess the problem I was looking at was not well written, and should have asked for integer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell of $x$ should be an integer or not. However, if this is specified then, I would partition the right hand side as
$$
2^x = \frac{48}{6-x} - 8
$$
So $6-x$ must divide 48 and $6-x>0$. So only possible values are $x=2,3,4,5$.  Saves one choice of $x$.

If nothing is known about $x$ then not much can be said.

Comment: I think you are right; $x$ should probably be an integer. I've edited the question to reflect this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming   $x$ to be a positive integer we have, $$2^{x-3}=\frac x{6-x}$$

For real $x,$ the Left hand Side is strictly positive

If $x>0,$ we need $\displaystyle 6-x>0\iff x<6\iff 0<x<6,$ observe that $x=2,3,4$ are actually solutions

If $x<0,$ we need $\displaystyle 6-x<0\iff x>6$  which is impossible

Comment: You have proven that all solutions lie within the interval $(0,6)$, but how would you go about locating the solutions?

Comment: @AustinMohr, observe my assumption in the first line

Comment: The two sides are [remarkably close](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2F%286-x%29-+2%5E%7Bx-3%7D+from+2+to+4) on the interval [2,4].

Comment: @labbhattacharjee OP does not indicate that $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Just edited the question -- I think there might be a mistake in the problem I was looking at. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer :

Hints :

$2^x(6-x)=8x$ can be seen as :

$$2^x(6-x)=2.(4x)$$

$$2^x(6-x)=4.(2x)$$

$$2^x(6-x)=8(x)$$

You have to check which could be the possible case...

Only two of these three equations makes sense...

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $x$ is an integer (or else I simply am not following the hint).

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: @AustinMohr :
 
I am not assuming $x$ is an integer... I am just saying one integer solution can be drawn from this idea..